# SQL Server 2014 can't login after detach database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using using Windows server and I'm having trouble logging in to SQL Server 2014.

A few days ago I changed default user from master database to new one. But today I opened SQL Server Management Studio.

I detach that database by right-clicking on it. After that, I disconnect from SQL Server Management Studio and then connect again.

Check: Windows authentication

Click OK

I get an error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider) error:233

When I try more to fixed it, now I get this error:

> Login Failed for user A. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18461)

What causes this error and how do I login again and attach my database?
Can I login to master database?

Comment: OP, I wouldn't recommend accepting answers that don't solve your issue. It will make other users avoid the question. This might help with your troubleshooting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/diagnostic-connection-for-database-administrators?view=sql-server-ver15. Definitely note this line `By default, the connection is only allowed from a client running on the server. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is by starting SQL instance in minimum config mode.

```
NET START MSSQLSERVER /f
```

Once you connect to the instance from same cmd window, then change the Max memory setting :

```
 SQLCMD -S <ServerName>\<InstanceName> -E
```

A prompt occurs:

```
1>
```

Type the following:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Restart the instance from Configuration Manager.

More on sqlcmd here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: When I type this 'SQLCMD -S Server/Instance -E' I get error

Comment: server is your server name and instance is your instance name

Comment: Yes I know but it has error: could not open a connection to sqlserver

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/cannot-login-after-default-database-is-deleted

Comment: does this https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/ help

Comment: I don't understand why this post was [copied from another site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179623/only-one-administrator-can-connect-at-this-time-ms-sql-server-error-18461/179645). The answer does not address the question, which has nothing to do with memory, only attaching databases. How did this get upvoted and accepted when it does not answer the question?